# Can we share single table in DynamoDB to multiple application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm new to DynamoDB, we are recently looking for options to migrate our existing MySQL applications to DynamoDB. Since DynamoDB limits the table count to 256 per AWS region.  We have multiple micro-services
Eg: service for orders, Quotes, Product costing, Service support etc. So now even for a single customer We need to create tables = # of micro service. Hence we will be reaching this limit of 256 soon. As I'm new I'm learning about the Data modeling. Is there any way to model our DB to make it robust in such a way it supports multiple application.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to apply a relational schema to a database that is not really designed for that. While you can do relation modeling with dynamo, you really should reexamine your data model if you plan to migrate from RDBMS.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and make sure that items have a common relationship for items (i.e. they're all order records vs a single table containing orders, products and CMS content)  vs using them as a multi purpose table to handle what is essentially multiple tables records compounded together with no relation.

The 256 table limit, is actually a soft limit.

> For any AWS account, there is an initial quota of 256 tables per AWS Region.

You can contact AWS support to request an increase, this is simply to prevent a new user who might not be aware of how the service works from creating a substantial number of resources and incurring large costs.

I suggest going through with contacting AWS support to increase this quota, and then continue with architecting your tables for the purpose they should be used for.

Also take a look at [Best Practices for Designing and Architecting with DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html).

Comment: I don't think the soft limit is primarily designed to be there to prevent users from incurring large costs. Instead, the soft limit is there to force you to talk to them and make sure you know what you are doing. Of course, there are other reasons too. For example, in some cases, AWS needs to provision more resources to meet your limit increase request.

Comment: According to docs "AWS implements quotas to provide highly available and reliable service to all customers, and protect you from unintentional spend.". However, I believe we are both correct, new users may not understand how to use services efficiently that leads to an increase in the spend. I see quotas as the stabilisers for your bike :)